# How can i fix "Error: Exception: Unsupported operation: Process.run"?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, sdk

[image: Error message]

[image: Flutter doctor output]

I tried to reinstall but it didn't fix the issue.
I use IntelliJ IDEA und first tried with the plugins flutter and dart.

Comment: What does your code look like in FocusShortcuts.dart?

Comment: Also, please include the error message in textform, not only as an image

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run a program which contains a call to `Process.run` while you are trying to run the application in a web browser. The `dart:io` (where `Process.run` are defined) are not, in general, available when you target browsers. This makes kinda sense since `Process.run` is used to start an arbitrary executable on your computer which would be a big security issue if possible from a web browser.

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks very much it was exactly that. and i was stuck for too long for this simple reason.